# How i can add an image to a imagelist from a picturebox in .net?

Tags: .net

I have a `picturebox` with an image and i want to add it to an `imagelist`.

How i do this?

I tried to do

`ImageList1.Images.AddStrip(PictureBox1.Image)`
and
`ImageList1.Images.Add(PictureBox1.Image)`

Comment: What's the error that you're getting when you try those methods? You need to describe your problem and include some code that you are trying in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ImageList.ImageCollection.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh5d0khx(v=vs.110).aspx) method actually accepts a variety of different parameters (`Icon`,`Image`, etc.) so you'll just need to ensure that what you are passing in is of the same type.

The [`PictureBox.Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx) property should return an `Image` object, which is a valid parameter for the previously mentioned `Add()` method, so the following should work :

```
ImageList1.Images.Add(PictureBox1.Image);
```

Using a very basic example, I created a `PictureBox`, added an Image to it and then added that image to the `ImageList` and you can see below that the `Count` of the number of images in the list is 1 :

[image]

So the image is being added as expected. Are you receiving any errors when you are setting this? What doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/52ebuiux01vbwz6/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=1" width="409" height="121">  

I tried this an i get this error:
"the reference to a member not shared requires a reference of an object"

Comment: Where is your `ImageList` defined? Shouldn't you use the `ImageList` that you just created, i.e. `imageListSmall.Images.Add(PictureBox1.Image);`

Comment: Sorry. I didn't cut the line above. That line is another `ImageBox`. Im using `ImageBox1`, That is declared in the graphic part of the form